# select2 4.0.0 can't select items with remote data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, thymeleaf, jquery-select2

i'm using select2 to load chunks of data from REST web service. The data is succesfully loaded with scrolling but the elements inside it cannot be selected data is loaded but not selected

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <select id="test" style="width: 300px" />
</div>
```

javaScript:

```
$("#test").select2({
    ajax: {
        url: "URL",
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function(params) {
            return {
                searchTerm: params.term, // search term
                page: params.page
            };
        },
        processResults: function(data, params) {
            params.page = params.page || 0;
            return {
                results: data.content,
                pagination: {
                    more: (1 + params.page) < data.totalPages
                }
            };
        },
        cache: true
    },
    allowClear: true,
    escapeMarkup: function(markup) {
        return markup;
    },
    multiple: true,
    maximumSelectionLength: 22,
    placeholder: "Select fruits...",
    templateResult: formatRepo,
    templateSelection: formatRepoSelection
});

function formatRepoSelection(data) {
    return data.hostname;
}

function formatRepo(data) {
    if (data.loading) return data.text;
    var markup = "<option value='"+data.hostname+"'>" + data.hostname + "</option>"
    return markup;
}
```

This the output data which is json object with one attribute "content" that has a list of "hostname" as value
[image]

Comment: Can you post the result returned by the ajax call? Or put this on a fiddle ?

Comment: @B.Assem i added a screenshot for the output data

Comment: checkout my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you are returning from server are not well formatted to be used by select2 : select2 expects each value to be a pair of id/text, so in your **processResults** you need to format the result and also you need to modify the two render functions based on the fact that the data parameter will contain two attributes ID and TEXT:

```
$("#test").select2({
    ajax: {
        url: "URL",
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function(params) {
            return {
                searchTerm: params.term, // search term
                page: params.page
            };
        },
        processResults: function(data, params) {
            var d = [];

            for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
              d.push({
                id: data[i].hostname, 
                text: data[i].hostname
              });
            }

            params.page = params.page || 0;
            return {
                results: d,
                pagination: {
                    more: (1 + params.page) < data.totalPages
                }
            };
        },
        cache: true
    },
    allowClear: true,
    escapeMarkup: function(markup) {
        return markup;
    },
    multiple: true,
    maximumSelectionLength: 22,
    placeholder: "Select fruits...",
    templateResult: formatRepo,
    templateSelection: formatRepoSelection
});

function formatRepoSelection(data) {
    return data.text;
}

function formatRepo(data) {
    if (data.loading) return data.text;

    return data.text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post I wanted to post for anyone else how may run into a similar situation and wanted to expand on the answer given by @B.Assem

For the "processResults" function, if you have multiple values returned that you want displayed next to each available selection you should assign them to their own key value pairs and then you can access them in your "templateResult" function.

```
ajax:{
 processResults: function(data, params) {
        var r = JSON.parse(data);
        var d = [];
        $.each(r.customers, function(i,e){
          var o = {
            id: e.myID, // id for selection
            text: e.textToFillInput, // Will be used as diplay value for input on selection
            otherData: e.otherData, // some more data
            firstName: e.firstName, // another item
            etc: e.etc // etc...
          }
          d.push(o);// Push to array
        }

        return {
            results: d,
            pagination:{more:false|true} // is expected and should be a boolean
            }
  };
},
templateResult:function(data){
     console.log(data.id)
     console.log(data.text)
     console.log(data.otherData)
     console.log(data.firstName)
     console.log(data.etc)
},
templateSelection:function(data){
  return data.text || 'Default Text';
}
```